# Items not inserting into SQLite database in Flask application - no errors showing

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask

Im attempting to insert into a SQL database from a form in a flask app.

I have tried altering the way I pass the arguments into query

```
g.db.execute("INSERT INTO subs(sub_name, price, pay_period, pay_date, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [subscription, price, period, pay_date, '1'])
```

I have tried entering as a tuple. tried individual arguments (this causes an error function only takes 2 arguments).

My SQL table schema

```
CREATE TABLE subs (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, sub_name TEXT, price FLOAT, pay_period TEXT, pay_date DATE, user_id INTEGER);
```

Maybe there is something wrong with my overall setup, the "/" get request works as expected so my database is connected.

Here is my full app code

```
import os
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, render_template, g, request
from werkzeug.utils import redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = sqlite3.connect('subzen.db')
    g.db.row_factory = dict_factory

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def index():
    
        subs = []
        for sub in g.db.execute('SELECT * FROM subs'):
            subs.append(sub) 

        return render_template("index.html", subs=subs)

@app.route("/add", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def add_sub():
    if request.method == "POST":
        subscription = request.form.get("subscription") 
        price = request.form.get("price")
        period = request.form.get("period")
        pay_date = request.form.get("pay_date")

        g.db.execute("INSERT INTO subs(sub_name, price, pay_period, pay_date, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [subscription, price, period, pay_date, '1'])

        return redirect('/')
    
    else:
        return render_template('add.html')

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    if hasattr(g, 'db'):
        g.db.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

def dict_factory(cursor, row):
    d = {}
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        d[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return d
```

Comment: make the list a tuple `(ubscription, price, period, pay_date, '1',)` and add a comma at end.

Comment: You need to call `commit` on the connection after inserting or updating.